# Sitecore 9.3 federated authentication onPrem Active Directory

Tags: identity-server

I am upgrading an 8.2 instance with Active Directory Module to 9.3. But I can't find much information about connecting IS4 to Active Directory. Has anyone connected federated authentication with an onPrem Active Directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore 9.3 will not work with Active Directory Module directly. In Sitecore 8.2, the AD module allows you to sync the AD on-prem users into Sitecore. This is no longer possible in Sitecore 9.3

In Sitecore 9.3 I will recommend using the Active Directory Federation Service (ADFS) approach instead.

Since you can use Sitecore Identity as federation gateway, you can configure SI to federate with ADFS (Ws-Federation) sub provider. This will involve creating a Sitecore Host plugin for ADFS sub-provider, register this with your SI using the guidance from [Sitecore Docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html). This will involve mapping claims for example.

Happy to provide more guidance if needed.

I have blogged this in detail, so I will recommend [review this for further information](https://360agileweb.wordpress.com/2020/02/28/sitecore-host-part-three/). I have also blogged and have sample [ADFS plugin ready to use and adapt](https://360agileweb.wordpress.com/2020/03/02/sitecore-host-part-four/)

Comment: I believe that the user will be taken to the Sitecore login page, where they will have to login with their AD credentials?

Comment: It depends how you want to play this. (A)You can  have the normal Sitecore login page, with the additional login button for ADFS. So your CMS users can either login using accounts managed in Sitecore, or use the ADFS login. Clicking on the ADFS login button will redirect to the ADFS login page. (B)You can completely bypass Sitecore login page, and instead re-direct users to the ADFS login page directly.

Comment: In your example code, is the authority just the ADFS url? <Authority>https://adfs.client.internal/</Authority>

Comment: The error I get is " Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]' "

Comment: Looks like you went with the Ids4Adfs which is an OpenId client for ADFS. The <Authority> is the ADFS URL available from the configuration page. For example when using Azure AD, this is in the form: <Authority>https://login.microsoftonline.com/some_GUID/</Authority>

Comment: I am also trying to connect SC 9.3 to on prem ADFS 2019.  I followed the example in your blog post but it isn't working.  After I sign in with my credentials on the ADFS site it just sends me right back to the Identity Server sign in page. I am wondering if I don't have things configured properly in ADFS.  Do you have any guidance as to how the Relying Trust has to be set up in ADFS?  We are trying to use WS-Fed.

Comment: @Corey if you’re able to redirect to ADFS login page, then your ADFS side looks okay. You need to debug Sitecore instance side to verify ADFS claims are mapped as expected. Can you share your SI plug-in configuration?

Comment: @JuliusA I am not completely sure that the ADFS stuff is set up correctly.  When I go to sign in I don't see a normal ADFS login page.  Instead I get a little pop-up that looks like an old Windows NTLM dialog box asking for my username and password.  Shouldn't I see a full ADFS login page?

Comment: Also - how can I share my config with you?  I can't paste it here because it is too long.

Comment: Maybe my blog post Can help https://blog.istern.dk